# Connecting Android phone to PC doesn't work anymore

Tags: android, hardware-interface

When I connect my phone (an HTC Hero running Eclair) to my PC (running Vista), the phone begins charging but doesn't connect to the pc. I can't access the SD card or install apps from Eclipse on it. Normally, the phone would ask me what kind of connection I want (charging, storage, sync, tether) but now nothing happens on my phone. I haven't installed any apps the last few days, and a week ago everything still worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port?

Comment: This is happening to me as well.  Just upgraded to 2.3.4.  Something is amiss.

Comment: I don't think this affects the Hero, but I'm putting this here for others: The Droid Bionic requires the usb cord that came with the phone to connect to a computer. Other usb cables do not work. No, this doesn't make any sense at all, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

adb kill-server
adb start-server
?